# Min and Max TypeError

Tags: python, function, max, min

For some reason i can not understand,a TypeError occures when using min and max functions.. 
Here is the code:
import random
from typing import List, Any, Union

```
list1 = []

for i in range(0,200):
    x = random.randint(1,50)
    list1.append(x)

list2 = [ j for j in range(0,51)]

list1.append(list2)
print(list1)

del list1[99:130]

print(len(list1))

print(min(list1))
```

And this is the error:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Thank you :)

Comment: Please follow the code of conduct.  Restructure your code snippet, it is very difficult to understand it.

Comment: Try `list1.extend(list2)` instead of `list1.append(list2)` - search the docs for explanation (is simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list1.append(list2)` adds `list2` (which is indeed a list) as an additional element to the end of `list1`. Your error arises because Python can't find the minimum of a list which consists of several numbers and one list.

I think you wanted to add all the individual numbers in `list2` to `list1`, to end with a list of just numbers. This can be done using `extend`, rather than `append`.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have a nested list (`list1`)
see on the example

```
f = [12,3,4,5,[1,2,3]]
In [25]: min(f)                                                                                                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-d9448f4534d8> in <module>
----> 1 min(f)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Thank you but i am a newbie..Explaining it would be helpful (Just a few words :P)

Comment: Thank you all very much ! I appreciate your time and effort :)